# OpenCycleMap tile configuration

Tags: openstreetmap, generate-tiles

I have successfully configured [Mapnik and generate_tiles.py](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Creating_your_own_tiles) on my computer so I can generate Mapnik tiles from the OpenStreetMap map database.

However, I would like to generate tiles similar to OpenCycleMap's ones. If I'm right tile configuration is in the `osm.xml` file. Is this configuration of OpenCycleMap available somewhere on the internet? If yes, where?

Answer (score 2):

As commented by @AndreJ:

> The OpenCycleMap is done by https://github.com/gravitystorm. You have
>   to ask him if he wants to share the style. As far as I know, he does
>   not.

and @scai:

> Correct, the OpenCycleMap style is not public unfortunately.

Comment: ... but you can create your own style. I'm rendering transparent tiles of cycling routes to be displayed over  a standard basemap. See http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/DE:Ajoessen/myMapnik#Radrouten (only in German) for some details. You might need to adapt the style grammar to modern Mapnik versions.